# Corona discharge due to SMT packages in high voltage applications

Tags: high-voltage, corona

I can't find a source on this matter. I would like to know if it is viable to make high voltage (100kV) resistor dividers with SMT type components. The square chip shapes have relatively sharp edges so I would not be surprised to see corona discharge due to their geometry. Experience from fellows here with such applications or any with similar voltages containing SMT type components, or some suggested sources would be appreciated.

Comment: Corona discharge occurs because of **local** field gradient. Look up 'HV grading rings' to get an idea of what's needed. Not rings *per se*, but conductors there. As you are using resistors, you automatically get a nice field gradient along the composite resistor.

Comment: If there are some "fast" transients on 100 kV, don't forget "capacitive effects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since air breaks down [as low as ~10 kV/cm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250040/what-exactly-is-breakdown-voltage-of-air) at 1 atmosphere, your 100 kV divider would need to be at least 10 cm long, with more of the length take up by the resistors (which distribute the voltage gradient) than by conductors. E.G., if you use resistors in the [0805 form factor](https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/surface-mount-resistor-sizes.html), 2 mm long, you'd need at least 50 resistors in series.

While this might be feasible, would it not be more efficient to use high-voltage resistors, e.g., [these from Genvolt](https://www.genvolt.com/application-information/514748ba52614/High-Voltage-Resistors-Up-To-1000kV)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. But i am not asking about design, but if corona discharge may happen due to the SMT chip geometry. That phenomenom is independent of how many resistors i use.

Comment: @Stonie, no, the **number** of resistors is the **main factor** whether corona discharge occurs, if there are no other nearby objects. Each resistor is tiny, perhaps 2 or 3 mm. A voltage gradient across a 2 mm resistor of 2 kV or less is sufficient to cause corona or even arcing at 1 atm. pressure. The resistors distribute the voltage, so the **gradient** decrease with greater length.